# flexing operation fails when structure is too long

Tags: solidworks

I have a linear repeat such  that for up to  11 repeats, the  flex operation works perfectly.  for 12 and  more, the operation goes haywire.  is there an alternate way of doing it that avoids this problem? 
the operation  is as follows:  [image: the operation]
this is the operation for 11 repeats (works perfectly) [image: up to 11 repeats, works great]

this is what I get for anything beyond 11 repeats:  [image: beyond 11, it fails]

the basic patern is as follows: [image: basic patern]  it is first linearly repeated (up to 11 times, apparently), then circular patterned around an axis, then the flex (twist) operation is applied.

edit:  it has been suggested to use weldmets.  I'm now getting the hang of this,  but it still has problems..[image]  ..sigh..  my order of operations:  [image]

Comment: Why not flex one, and then pattern afterwards?

Comment: Also **use weldements**. It's crazy to be using sweeps for this.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I would have flexed then patterned, but don't know how.  tried flexing, and  it worked :-)  actually, I'm flexing then patterning, manually (crudely).  as for weldments, you could say I'm exploring the limits of the basic operations of the  software before I move on  to the  fancier parts.  this -would- actually seem like a great time to learn  weldements ;-)

Comment: to patern  afterward, one would have to code the twist into the pattern, which I don't (yet) know how to do.  maybe there is a simple way?  to explore :-)

Comment: Weldments 'aint fancy ;) and rotation along a linear pattern has been around since 2018 https://hawkridgesys.com/blog/solidworks-2018-whats-new-rotate-linear-pattern

Comment: @JonathanRSwift  smartypants :-P  you rock! :-D

Comment: @JonathanRSwift  sigh.  I've now tried your weldmets solution.. and I understand some  of  why you think it's so great, but it fails for me in a few ways.  first, I'm unable to specify my own cross-section, my system isn't setup right, don't have permission.  second..  when I go to twist the thing, I have  to, it seems, select each piece individually.  there are a lot of them.  as for  rotation along a linear pattern, that's next up :-)

Comment: You can just start with any existing and then go in and edit the sketch to create your own profile.

Comment: You can use weldments to create the shape and then merge into one solid body prior to the twist feature

Comment: modifying the profile works.  check! :-D

Comment: noooooo!!!!  it looked so promissing..  it was all working.. then the flex command messed  it  all up..  not totally..   I've added a screen-shot to the question..

Comment: See my second comment “*also* use weldments”. Still need to flex first pattern second.